# What should be included/imported to recognize "$" operation join function of in my spark -java code?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java8.
I am trying to join two data sets as below:

```
computed_df.as('s).join(accumulated_results_df.as('f),$"s.company_id" === $"f.company_id","inner")
```

Which is working fine in databrick's notebooks.

> But when I try to implement the same in my spark java code in my Ide.
>   It wont recognize the "$" function/operator even after including

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
```

So what should be done to use it in my spark java code ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`. See [This](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html).

> public class Column
>
> ...
>
> ```
> df("columnName")            // On a specific DataFrame.
> col("columnName")           // A generic column no yet associcated with a DataFrame.
> col("columnName.field")     // Extracting a struct field
> col("`a.column.with.dots`") // Escape `.` in column names.
> $"columnName"               // Scala short hand for a named column.
> expr("a + 1")               // A column that is constructed from a parsed SQL Expression.
> lit("abc")                  // A column that produces a literal (constant) value.
> ```